# Beginner Scheme: How to write string-downcase

Tags: scheme, racket

I was just wondering while reading my textbook how someone could write string-downcase for beginners in scheme? Thank so much!

I know how to do it using map but I was wondering if there was a more basic way to do it so that beginners to scheme can understand without knowing what map does. Thanks!

Comment: Just use a recursive call instead of map.  IMO map is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time I'll write the general idea of the algorithm, you should know by now how to write this up using a template:

1. Transform the string to a list of characters, using `string->list`
2. Iterate over the list, and transform each character to lowercase using `char-downcase`
3. Build a new list with the newly transformed characters
4. Finally, transform back the resulting list using `list->string`

Basically we're *mapping* over the characters in the string. There are several fancy ways to do this, for instance using [sequences](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=sequences), or [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29), etc. but for now, I believe is better that we stick to the basics and learn how to do this from scratch.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried but because of my code involves only one letter, it gave me an error that said expected a list of char but got /#j

Comment: That's because you passed a single char when a list was expected, try building something simple first - say, transform a single char to lower case. Then, a list of chars. Then, a string. Go step by step, you'll get the hang of it by first doing simple examples and making sure you understand how they work

Comment: To get the first letter of the word to be lower case I have 

    (list->string(char-downcase(first(string->list name))))

Comment: Nevermind I didn't know I just had to make the single char into a list of one. Thank you!